# Error making a job on a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi, kubernetes-cluster

I'm trying to make a job that runs sysbench on a pod. First I make the job with the next yaml:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: sysbench-prepare
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: sysbench-prepare
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sysbench-prepare
        image: severalnines/sysbench
        command:
        - sysbench
        - --db-driver=mysql
        - --oltp-table-size=100000
        - --oltp-tables-count=24
        - --threads=1
        - --mysql-host=localhost
        - --mysql-port=3306
        - --mysql-user=sbtest
        - --mysql-password=password
        - /usr/share/sysbench/tests/include/oltp_legacy/parallel_prepare.lua
        - run
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Apparently, it is created without problem

```
pi@k8s-master-rasp4:~ $ kubectl get jobs
NAME               COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
sysbench-prepare   0/1           33m        33m
```

And this is the yaml for the pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app: sysbench
  name: sysbench
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - sysbench
    - --db-driver=mysql
    - --report-interval=2
    - --mysql-table-engine=innodb
    - --oltp-table-size=100000
    - --oltp-tables-count=24
    - --threads=64
    - --time=99999
    - --mysql-host=localhost
    - --mysql-port=3306
    - --mysql-user=sbtest
    - --mysql-password=password
    - /usr/share/sysbench/tests/include/oltp_legacy/oltp.lua
    - run
    image: severalnines/sysbench
    name: sysbench
  restartPolicy: Never
```

And this is the state  after creating it

```
pi@k8s-master-rasp4:~ $ kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS   RESTARTS   AGE
sysbench                 0/1     Error    0          66s
sysbench-prepare-4st28   0/1     Error    0          56s
sysbench-prepare-88kcd   0/1     Error    0          61s
sysbench-prepare-kbk5c   0/1     Error    0          46s
sysbench-prepare-zrv95   0/1     Error    0          6s
```

The log shows this error:

```
pi@k8s-master-rasp4:~ $ kubectl logs -f sysbench
standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

Everything is running on a raspberry cluster, anyone knows where could be the problem? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to run a [linux/amd64](https://hub.docker.com/r/severalnines/sysbench/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated) image on an ARM-based system: essentially, the error is saying that doesn't understand how to run instructions since binary and processor are speaking different languages.

You have to find a compatible Docker image for your architecture.